# jQuery submit not called on button click

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I am trying to submit a form on a button click.

"alert 1" shows up but "alert 2" inside the `submit()` doesn't. Could you tell me why?

**HTML**

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="">

    <input type=button id="send">SEND</a>

</form>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('body').delegate('#send', 'click', function () {

    alert('alert 1');

    $('form').submit(function (event) {

        alert('alert 2')
        event.preventDefault()

    });

});
```

Here is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/bvV2W/

Comment: When did you submit the form? Please go through: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Comment: It's better to make use of __on__ instead of __delegate__. Like `$('body').on('click', '#send', function () {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that: you don't make the submit, you have only a button not a submit button.

Is lig that doens't enter into the function submit because you don't make a submit event

try to change your button to this:

```
<input type=submit id="send">SEND</a>
```

or try this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">

$('body').delegate('#send', 'click', function() {
        alert('alert 1');
        $('#form').trigger('submit');
        $('#form').submit(function (event) {
                alert('alert 2')
                event.preventDefault()

        });
    );
```

Comment: I tried it in fiddle. Doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/bvV2W/2/ . COuld you post a working fiddle?

Comment: Click Tidyup in jsfiddle, there is syntax error!
'}' is missing

check this http://jsfiddle.net/bvV2W/4/

Answer (score -1):

because this way you're attaching a function to the `submit` event. It will be raised when you submit your form but you aren't doing it anywhere.

You need to call the `submit` event after that by writing:

```
$('form').submit(); // no arguments
```